# Xcode - UnitTest using XCTest

Tags: xcode, macos, unit-testing, xctest

I have a project created in Xcode 4. It is converted to Xcode 5. Using Xcode 5 IDE I am trying to add unit tests. This is what I have done

- Added a new target of type "Cocoa Unit testing Bundle".
- "Symbols hidden by default" is switched to NO for main app target.

Still I am getting the following linker error

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MyUtils", referenced from:
>   objc-class-ref in MyApp_Tests.o

What is it that I have missed here? I am trying not to add all my classes to unit test target.